# Clicking on an unlocked cell on a protected sheet is unprotecting the sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, protected

I have a workbook with multiple sheets.  There are unlocked and locked cells.  I have a macro to protect all sheets.

After I run the macro and all sheets are protected, when I then click on a cell that is unlocked, the sheet it is on is suddenly becoming unprotected.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

I want users to be able to interact with the unlocked cells, while keeping the sheet protected so that they can't make changes to the locked cells.

Comment: We can't comment without seeing the workbook itself.

Comment: It would also be useful to see the relevant code

Comment: As far as I know you can use this feature with Protect Worksheet directly, you should provide the code here.